# how to push fping.exe (or other ping for windows) to terminate on first reply?

Tags: windows, networking, ping, icmp

Want to ping specific host with arbitrary number of ICMP requests, but also want to ping program terminate on first reply (speed-up script). Built-in windows ping and few other I tested have not such feature. Anyone known windows ping program with this ability? I know I can loop ping program with "-n 1" parameter, but this cause to ping program is started each time loop running and in case of massive usage could cause unwanted system load.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in PowerShell, which as the `Test-Connection` cmdlet as a wrapper for ping.

```
 param(
     [string]$Name = "8.8.8.8",
     [int]$count = 4
 )

 [bool]$Success = $false

 For ($i=0; $i -le $count; $i++) {

     $result = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     if ($result.StatusCode -eq 0)
     {
          $Success = $true
          $result 
          break;
     }
 }

 Write-Output "Successful connection: $Success"
```

Test-Connection always uses a single ping, and I put a loop around it, as soon as a ping is successful, we are breaking out of the loop, ideally after the first ping, Otherwise it try x times, as specified in $count.

PowerShell is not starting the ping.exe executable, it uses the network APIs underneath, so it may perform a bit better under load.

Comment: Well and how is it with powershell interpreter itself start load? cmd.exe and conhost.exe start takes very minimal system resources. I am talking about system which monitor hundreds targets every minute and machine is not dedicated.

Comment: The PowerShell process itself is indeed much heavier than cmd.exe and the start-up will take longer. But depending on your requirements you may be able to monitor all targets with a single script.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `-n` [parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490968.aspx)

> -n   Count   : Specifies the number of Echo Request messages sent. The default is 4.

`ping.exe -n 1` should send only one Echo Request message

If you are looking to speed up things you might want to check the other parameters as well, specifically the `timeout` parameter.

Comment: Have you read question carefully? I know about this option, but do no want it.